# Error while executing PowerShell code

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

My code is not printing the value stored in the array, it is printing `System.Collections.Hashtable[$i]`.

```
$text = Read-Host
$id = @{}
for ($i=0; $i -le $text; $i++)
{
    $id[$i] = Read-Host
}
for ($i=0; $i -le $text; $i++)
{
    Write-Host $id[$i] 
}
```

Ouput:

```
PS C:\Users\mifi>.\1.ps1
2
Keshav
kk
kk
System.Collections.Hashtable[0]
System.Collections.Hashtable[1]
System.Collections.Hashtable[2]
```

[image: This is the Screenshots of the Ouput]

Whenever I was running this code the Output results in the above form.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I copy past your code I get the desired output.

Comment: @MartinBrandl have a look at the screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your code? `$id[i]` instead of the desired `$id[$i]`?  Why do you use Notepad to edit Powershell scripts? The ISE would help you avoiding some errors or would even help you finding them.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not post code you fabricated or typed from memory. You're getting output like

```
System.Collections.Hashtable[0]
System.Collections.Hashtable[1]
System.Collections.Hashtable[2]
```

because in your *actual* code you have a statement

```
Write-Host "$id[$i]"
```

rather than the line

```
Write-Host $id[$i]
```

your sample code pretends to have.

PowerShell does only simple variable expansion inside double quoted strings. It does not expand more complex expressions (like index or property access) the way one might expect. An expression `"$id[$i]"` is expanded to the string representation of the variable `$id` (which in this case is the name of the object's class: "System.Collections.Hashtable"), followed by an opening square bracket, the value of the variable `$i`, and a closing square bracket.